# What to do after a pure math academic path?

Tags: soft-question, career, advice

I don't know whether my question is in the appropriate place. I've studied physics, and then did a PhD in (pure) math and 2 postdocs. I definitely love math research, but I am not ready to apply all over the world hoping to find a position somewhere sometimes. Therefore I am looking for a job.

I don't have any interest in anything from the society. I only love math for its beauty. I am wondering what happened to the world. All jobs I am looking for with "math diploma" requirement seems to be in [data science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_science) or finance. I hate this stuff and don't see the relation with math, at least the math that I like. I cannot see any beauty in data science and worse, in finance.

Does anyone have an idea of not-so-sad job openings? Is it our fate to change our career paths to finance if we had a pure math-physics academic background?
Sorry for these desperate questions, but I feel so lost and sad….

Comment: I'm not sure if anything has "happened to the world" - 30 years ago data science didn't exist, and your only choice was finance. Also, data science and finance are both huge fields, and I have to wonder how hard you've actually looked for beauty (mathematical or otherwise) in them. How much do you know about the theory of stochastic differential equations? Information theory? Bayesian inference?

Comment: There's always secondary school teaching, but that can be hard if you're not called to it. But I would take a broader view of the high-tech industry. I have former PhD students working at places like Google, and they seem to enjoy the day-to-day challenges of their job, and seem mostly fairly happy. There's also a broader message I would give you that I think is important for people thinking about leaving academia.  In the culture of academia, there is a strong emphasis of intensely loving mathematics itself, and (continued)

Comment: tying your sense of meaning and satisfaction very directly to your work. I think I'm lucky in that neither of my parents were academics, so I grew up with a better sense of how normal people relate to their job. Namely, they both liked their jobs, but less because of what they did and more because they liked their coworkers a lot and found their work mostly not too boring. Neither of them would say that their job gave their life meaning (that came from their family, community, hobbies, etc.). I think that's a healthier way to live, to be honest.

Comment: I wouldn't only look for jobs that "math" as a requirement, a lot of the tech field would be something you can jump into and may not explicitly require math (but certainly benefit from some rigorous thinking). If money isn't the primary motivator then you also have areas like policy-making and think tanks you can apply for that would benefit from your analytic skills

Comment: As someone in a similar boat, I've chosen to pursue a career path that gives me plenty of time to dedicate to mathematics research -- I don't know what country you're in, but in America being a firefighter is a fantastic option. Good pay, you get to sit at the firehouse working on whatever if there are no fires, and you usually have 3-4 days a week off. (Also you can pursue a degree in fire science all the way up to a PhD if you like, and this improves your career prospects for being a fire chief etc.)

Comment: @AlecRhea yes that's great. I also hope to have time to continue my research, once i find a solution to my life... I live in Switzerland, I'm a lady, not sure I'm ready to become a firefighter ;) it's great if it works for you!

Comment: Ah, I understand -- best of luck. (and I totally agree that data science/finance sound... yeesh!)

Comment: @PaulSiegel of course it is my personal vision of the world and of life, it is a matter of taste and philosophical point of view of life, but i do not like the concept of money, so working in finance would be very hard. Also learning something I don't have any interest in is very difficult to me.

Comment: @AndyPutman thanks for the tips. That's also another problem in my personal life, i haven't found my soul mate neither but i don't think people on this forum can help me on this ^^. So finding a not-too-annoying job is important to me.

Comment: @coco: I can only imagine the terrible advice you would get here re that!  I would focus on choosing a place where you would like to live, and then get deeply involved in your local community.  Fundamentally, other people (not necessarily family!) are a more stable source of happiness and meaning than a job.

Comment: You might also watch [this interview of Saul Glasman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3SzIbVfeUw).

Comment: @coco I think you will struggle to find any sort of employment that does not interact with the concept of money - even academic jobs are funded by tuition money and research grants. But if it would suffice for the work itself to interact with financial considerations minimally, then you can consider data science jobs in health care, technology, supply chain, etc.

Comment: @Alec Rhea: Very interesting career path! I'm reminded of [this mathoverflow user](https://mathoverflow.net/users/5090/mathematrucker) who is a professional truck driver. I've had several math literature exchanges with him over the past 10-15 years, mainly with regard to [this pet project of his](https://www.mathtransit.com/cornucopia.php).

Comment: It might be helpful to take a step back and think about what you like to do and are good at, and not just what will be most similar to what you’ve been doing. Do you like to write? Do you like build systems? Do you like to explain things? There might be other local maxima you’ll like that aren’t just “math but less fun.”

Comment: Also you might consider therapy if you have affordable options. Unhappy and going through an enormous life change is the model situation for a couple months of talking to a counselor.

Comment: Take a look at this MSE question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/can-i-use-my-powers-for-good

Comment: My perspective is that in the real world you either have to be genius or have a lot of money (sufficient amount of money for your purpose) to be able to do the things you truly care about. If the first option is not viable then the next best thing is to figure our out the money situation. BTW having an academic job without being a genius (whatever that might mean) can turn into the worst nightmare, it turns into the game of pleasing others in the hope of potentially getting a permanent job.

Comment: Coco, since you are in Switzerland, did you try to speak to people, say in the EPFL or the ETH and ask for their advice. I think you can find there mathematicians which do interesting work in relation with industries. Examples: There is a big key-producer in Switzerland: They need mathematicians for combinatorial problems when developping keys. Another example: The (now retired) professor for applied math at the University of Neuchatel computed 'spectra of lakes' (given by solving Laplacian-operators on a domain given by the lake). The initial motiviation was where to put most efficiently

Comment: oxygen in the lakes when they have a lack of it. There are interesting math problems in the robot-industry (another swiss-speciality) where mathematicians are useful and so on. Try to go to a few math departements and speak to the people there (especially the applied mathematicians can have useful contacts).

Comment: Try contacting someone at https://80000hours.org/

Comment: Perhaps you could get more helpful suggestions about possible career paths if you told us a little more about what area of math you've been working in.

Comment: And what physics you did.

Comment: I have friends who completed a Mathematics PhD and now teach mathematics at a secondary school, this may not be appealing to you though.  If you wish to continue staying involved in mathematics, teaching in schools is one possibility.

Comment: Can you say what "I am not ready to apply all over the world hoping to find a position somewhere sometimes" means in real terms? Can you paraphrase that, at least two different ways?

Similarly, can you say what "I don't have any interest in anything from the society" means?

Comment: My rep is too low to post an answer, but see my answer here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/184331/working-towards-an-academic-career-that-lets-me-do-research-in-two-largely-unc/184360#184360
The TLDR: there are tons of other fields where the mathematical applications lag the state of the art in mathematics significantly. If there's another field that's ever interested you, chances are that there are people open to collaborations with mathematicians. There are even grants for this type of thing (see NSF's Mathematical Biology grant as an example)

Comment: @SeanJ This post isn't really here for you to try to ''poach'' students to projects which you are working on.

Comment: @HollisWilliams, I think there's a fine line, but, if someone posts saying "I am not sure how to use my mathematical knowledge", the options are to mention fine generalities, or else to mention specifics.  (Another option seems to be to relate one's own personal experience, which may be motivating but is probably not directly useful.)  While there have been lots of pleasant generalities, surely it is a specific answer (such as, though not necessarily specifically, [@‍SeanJ's](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1114746)) that is likely to be most useful, even if it does smack of an advert?

Comment: @HollisWilliams poach from whom?  tbh that statement is so far from the truth I don't know where to begin.  this might help, small startup with no money etc.

Comment: @coco This company in Switzerland https://www.inait.ai has a strong presence of math PhD's.

Comment: @MaxMuller thanks for the link!

Comment: @Z.M thanks for the video!

Comment: @user127776 that's true, and it is very tiring to take so much time in the application process and my previous advisors also told me i should work on another project that i will (almost surely) succeed, just for the cv and list of publications! this is the negative part until getting a permanent position..

Comment: @RolandBacher thank you for your reply. Could you tell me which is this key producer in Switzerland? And who is this professor from Neuchatel working on spectra of lakes?

Comment: @Pulcinella thanks for the link!

Comment: @StevenLandsburg I have been working in spectral graph theory during my PhD, then during my postdocs on random matrices and combinatorial problems and finally on partition functions of Yang-Mills theory :)

Comment: @JW theoretical physics and in particular cosmology :)

Comment: @HollisWilliams sure this would be an option. The thing is that high school teachers are involved in discipline problems rather than teaching maths. Also one needs to study 2 more years in order to have the right to teach here. I applied for teaching positions at university but didn't get it

Comment: @coco Discipline problems in high school?  This is not typically a problem in the UK because attendance at a high school is not compulsory, so students can essentially be told that they can leave if they do not wish to be there (I guess in other countries it might be a problem though).

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin i meant that i live in Switzerland and would like to stay here for several reasons. I do not want to live anywhere on the planet. I also meant that I am not convinced on the model of the society, on how it works, and i don't have any interest in finance, insurance, technologies and so on. I don't see the point

Comment: @HollisWilliams ha that's great. Unfortunately it is not like that in Switzerland. My former colleagues have actually these problems.

Comment: @anjama thanks for the link!

Comment: @coco  :  "I don't see the point" ...  I venture to guess that once upon a time you didn't see the point of Yang-Mills theory.   Sometimes when you learn a little about a subject, you start to see the point and then the subject changes from uninteresting to  interesting.  Maybe you should try the experiment of learning a little about finance or insurance or technologies.  It's not that hard to learn a little bit, and that little bit might open up whole new worlds for you.

Comment: Maybe start here:  https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.03417.pdf .  Or here:  https://simons.berkeley.edu/programs/spectral2014

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin MathOverflow is intended to be about what is relevant to researchers in maths. (Are you one?) I strongly believe that this question is relevant because researchers in maths who supervise PhD students encounter such situations in real life (for instance, the usual "career path" of academia requires making a lot of drastic decisions which some people cannot choose to make, as discussed in the OP). So this discussion forum has a critical mass of people whose expertise prepared them to give some meaningful answers to this particular question, which is the whole point.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko, while I don't agree personally with the very broad view of what's appropriate on MO, I certainly think your [point](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432931/what-to-do-after-a-pure-math-academic-path#comment1115392_432931) is well taken about how more questions might be appropriate here than would be apparent to the casual observer.  But let's not get into credential checking, such as asking whether other people are research mathematicians.  After all, non-research mathematicians, however placed the parentheses, are welcome here as well.

Comment: @LSpice what you see as credential checking I view as pointing out that a person who is interesting in maths recreationally is very likely to not understand the pertinence of the question to a research mathematician.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko I am not a maths researcher… merely someone who  saw a Question on SE and thought it looked rather vague and the author seemed rather lost. You might, and I don't think it's clear whether "What to do after a pure math academic path" means "In pursuit of…" or "coming to the end of…" or "having completed…", nor whether "the society" means his neighbours, or a professional association. I thought clarity might get Peter more specific Answers.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg well it is just a matter of personal tastes and interests, i am not saying i am right. Yes i do see interest in YM theory, and yes i do hate finance. Since i am not autonomous, i also "need" money but working in that sector would be very painful to me

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin indeed, the whole notion of "a pure math academic path" is difficult to comprehend for a non-mathematician, as almost every mathematician will have observed many times in their daily life. I would honestly suggest that you exercise some humility and avoid telling to mathematicians in what terms they should be talking about a serious real issue that arises in their profession.

Comment: @coco The key producer is 'Kaba' in Zug (german speaking part of Switzerland). I doubt that they need a mathematician every month but there are surely other similar jobs. Good luck!

Comment: Just chiming in to offer my support for @VladimirDotsenko's last few comments.

Comment: @coco for what it's worth, Switzerland has (in Zurich) one of the Google's programming hubs. Several people I know well who had a past life of studying to become mathematicians found their happiness there. I cannot be certain that this is a good thing for you personally to try, but it is something worth considering. If you wish you can contact me by email, and I can get you in touch with someone I know, they can tell you a bit what to expect.

Comment: @coco In the US, a path is law school. Some former mathematicians and physicists end up in patent law.  It can be very well-paid and legal documents should be easy for mathematicians to read.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thank you for your comment. I didn't get, you mean one should start again studies in law? how long does this take?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thank you for the idea, but i cannot study 3 years before starting to work, i need to pay my bills now.. :/

Comment: You are not able to get job a in academia in any institution? Why not try some college or university or school where you can teach math to people?

Comment: @Prem no i cannot find a job in academia, it is too competitive in Switzerland. I don't like to teach, also it is more about discipline than teaching and i am not able to educate kids that parents haven't been able to educate themselves...

Comment: @coco Of course teaching kids will be bad idea. I am talking about teaching students of higher grades. Why not go about this like Feynman did? He mixed original thinking in every topic that he taught. This made it fun for him as he discovered new perspectives. Also, he got to interact with students/answer their questions. He called this 'activity' that keeps things alive. The alternative would be to shut yourself down in a cottage and try to come up with original results. They may never come this way, without some 'activity'.

Comment: @coco also, teaching is an economic activity. Money is nothing but a token for having done some work that is useful for someone, which one can later exchange with someone else doing something useful for us. An alternative is becoming so good in a field that you can bargain and get paid just what you love. Again, Feynman had reached that stage. He taught because he wanted to, but did not do any administrative duty and never got fired for this. One can either become that good in a field or take a simple living route, doing just enough job to make ends meet and doing math in remaining time.

Comment: @Prem haha thank you for the idea, though i'm not sure to be as good as Feynman :)) I have kind of a social phobia so teaching everyday or almost everyday would be a lot of stress :/ I was just normal in my research, not a superstar, otherwise i would have found a position wherever i wanted, but if one is just normal then he doesn't choose where he lives..
Have you found a permanent position?

Comment: @coco I am a physics PhD student. I don't know how good I am, but worst case scenario, I will teach students at whatever place I get to. I love research and hopefully will also continue with it as I do some other job. I also have interest in AI and other economic stuff, so will try to make money through this route, although no idea how it will turn out.

Comment: @Prem I wish you good luck in your future! If you like AI and economics, you will find something you like for sure! :)

Answer (score 46):

I am sorry that the OP feels "desperate and sad." I agree with the comments suggesting that happiness in life is very different from achieving some specific career. I also think a lot has to do with mindset.

That said, there are zillions of jobs for mathematicians (far from data science and finance being the only options) and many of them involve working with beautiful mathematical concepts. Here are some examples, in no particular order:

- Use math to identify cases of gerrymandering and help create maps that are fair. This involves graph theory, geometry, metric spaces, and more. It's very cool and super relevant.
- Become a senior scientist or research mathematician at a tech company, like the sort that hired Jennifer Chayes, Laszlo Lovasz, Katalin Vesztergombi, etc. There is plenty of beautiful work to do in graph theory.
- Social network analysis is a lovely blend of mathematics and sociology. I saw a great talk by Strogatz on this topic once. I imagine companies like Meta might have teams of mathematicians studying social network graphs.
- Topological data analysis (TDA) is beautiful to a lot of people, and involves mathematical concepts such as graphs, metric spaces, Betti numbers, and a whole lot more. There are government and industry research groups based on TDA, and it's a growing area. Lots of jobs.
- Work for a government intelligence service. Plenty of connections to graph theory, number theory, etc. If you like your government and believe its mission is protecting people, then this kind of work can be immensely rewarding.
- Work for a government contractor, like the IDA in the USA. I know people in jobs like that who spend most of their time thinking about elliptic curves, group laws, error correcting codes, etc.
- Be an actuary. If you like probability theory and probability models, there are really fun topics that come up in this setting.
- I push back against the idea that there is no beauty in data science. Many data mining algorithms involve beautiful mathematics, like principal component analysis (eigenvectors, change of basis), singular value decomposition and separating hyperplanes, graph clustering algorithms, etc. Many companies have realized that if they want to get their modeling right, it's beneficial to have a trained mathematician onboard rather than only people who know how to run commands and have no idea why the algorithm works. I know data scientists who spend their time tweaking these algorithms to work in new settings, which means they are constantly playing with these beautiful concepts. Additionally, there is tremendous satisfaction in feeling like you created something that has the ability to really help a large number of people in their lives, e.g., statistical models to inform government policy and help lift people out of poverty, match people to jobs they will enjoy, help people who use drugs to get out of a state of addiction, etc.
- I know a lot of people who think Fourier analysis is beautiful and there's a whole branch of data science (spectral theory, time series models) where you get to play with this every day. Same for working for companies like Sound Hound or Shazam, and probably many others that I haven't listed (Zoom? Skype? How do they denoise? Some beautiful math must be in the background.)
- I concur with comments who said secondary school teaching can be a very fulfilling job, and one full of opportunities to enjoy (and share) the beauty of math. That's especially true if you work with the IMO team, programs for gifted high school students, etc. Such students can even do cool research and there have been lots of MO questions about that topic.
- I believe certain types of engineering use fairly sophisticated tools from analysis. Sadly, I'm not an expert in this.
- Text analysis, e.g., using and developing algorithms for determining authorship, extracting summaries, etc. Imagine developing an algorithm that can use Twitter data to figure out when an emergency is happening and then dynamically allocate government resources to help.
- Mathematical art, both creating it and using math to connect people with art in new ways (e.g., Google Deep Dream)
- Using math to create improved epidemiological models, e.g., while working for a hospital system, government, etc.

Others have compiled better lists than this, e.g., [the AMS has a list](https://www.ams.org/education/math-work) including the following and also a list of other lists.

- Climate study
- Animated films
- Astronomy and space exploration

I guess the message I want to impart to the OP is that there's a lot to be excited about and a lot to look forward to. Now that you're a trained mathematician, you can go in many directions. For almost any passion, there is a way to connect it to mathematics and to bring the beauty of math into that world. Go explore and play!

Comment: "Imagine developing an algorithm that can use Twitter data to figure out when an emergency is happening and then dynamically allocate government resources to help." This example made me smile, because my team has worked on this sort of problem before, but our contacts at Twitter get very anxious when you talk about using their data to collaborate with governments.

Comment: Wonderful response. I should add that a lot of mathematicians (especially young people) turn towards research in artificial intelligence and machine learning.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this long list of suggestions! As someone in a similar situation, this will definitely have an impact on my career.

Comment: Mathematics can turn up in some unexpected places - see Ian Stewart's [What's the Use?](https://www.amazon.com/Whats-Use-Mathematics-Shapes-Everyday-ebook/dp/B08PV59QN6), for instance. I was also surprised recently to happen across Tom Leinster's book: [Entropy and Diversity: The Axiomatic Approach](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/ed/) and to see some (to me) unexpected areas of mathematics applied to biodiversity.

Comment: Some of these wouldn't be jobs themselves, but a contract done by a consulting firm, for example. Anything overly specific might require OP to move. A lot require willingness to code.

Comment: ...Unfortunately, all these avenues have a premise that you actually do not suck at math, and do not really *have* to choose non-academic job. (...also the number of times collaboration with governmental/big corp global surveillance teams is mentioned makes me uncomfortable)

Comment: @PaulSiegel there are also private organizations like NGOs, which should be much lower risk than a government.

Comment: @DavidWhite thanks a lot for taking time and writing so many ideas! the thing is i haven't see any jobs with such requirements, so i don't see how i would sell myself in these fields

Comment: @justforplaylists indeed and i don't like to code, and i am not good at it

Comment: @coco Coding is a skill like any other, it takes practice to get good at, and can be frustrating if you aren't good at it yet. Are you completely opposed to all coding? Some jobs require a lot of complex algorithms, and some just require competency with certain tools or willingness to learn. For example, some analyst positions might use tools like R, Matlab, and Mathematica. Are you including those when you say you don't like coding, or do you mean you don't like things like Java, Python, and C++?

Comment: @justforplaylists well, i've learnt a bit of C++ during my studies and i use to have a regular and elementary use of Mathematica. I'm ok with a little use of it, not sure i would like to only code

Comment: @coco Yeah, C++ isn't a language that will make most people love coding. I think the jobs listed here most have some coding and some mathematics, and the exact ratio will vary by employer. Generally larger employers or highly focused (ex. consulting) will be able to hire more specialists. Job titles like "data scientist" and "analyst" are very broad and could have a lot of math, a lot of coding, both, or neither, so you need to check the individual posting to see what they're looking for.

Answer (score 21):

I love mathematics, too, but I don’t expect to get paid unless I do mathematics that makes money for my employer. Nothing has “happened to the world” — it has always been this way.

If you love mathematics purely for its beauty, and you don’t care whether it provides any value to society (or your employer), then perhaps you should think of yourself as an artist, like a painter, sculptor, or musician.

To make a living as an artist, you need an audience, and the audience for modern pure mathematics is extremely small. As a musician, you can go play on street corners, and maybe make enough money to live, but it’s a hard life. The modern equivalent of the street corner is a YouTube channel. You could try that, but most potential subscribers are looking for help with calculus, and wouldn’t be interested in your research work.

Another alternative is to look for a job as an academic mathematician. As you said, this will probably involve hunting around the world for a while, and you might have to go live somewhere that’s not as pleasant as Switzerland. You said you don’t want to do this. Fair enough. Your choice.

A third alternative is to take a job that provides you with enough cash to live, and yet still allows you enough free time to pursue your art. Then you don’t need to worry about finding an audience, and you can just do things that you personally find beautiful, regardless of what anyone else thinks of them — you’re free. You said you couldn’t be a firefighter, but there are other jobs that consist mostly of sitting and waiting. Many of these jobs don’t pay very well, but I’m guessing that this might not bother you.

If none of the above sounds appealing, then maybe it’s time to re-evaluate. Do you have to do mathematics research? Could you live without it? Is it as important to you as your friends, family, mental and physical health? Could you find the same beauty in some other discipline?

The way out for me (and many others) was through software development. Learning programming is easy enough, and it’s a highly marketable skill. You won’t use much of the mathematics you learned, but well-constructed software has much of the same elegance and beauty as mathematics (in my opinion). Something to consider.

Comment: Good answer. I am confused by the OP's comment, "I don't have any interest in anything from the society." But a job is something from the society and the OP is interested in a job. I am sympathetic to the OP's plight, but the starting point has to be a recognition that if you want something (a job) from society then you have to offer something in return. The OP [does not like the concept of money](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432931/what-to-do-after-a-pure-math-academic-path/432938#comment1114519_432931), but a job is something that an employer gives you money for doing.

Comment: +1 last paragraph – software development definitely benefits from rigorous/logical thinking and good sense, though some practitioners are loath to admit it.

Comment: The problem with software is that your employer is most likely to want you to create poorly-constructed software cheaply and quickly rather than create well-constructed software.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo I don’t know if I’d agree with “most likely”, but some employers certainly think that way. Writing shoddy software cheaply and quickly might maximize short-term profits, but damage long-term ones. And without short-term profits, there is no long term, in some companies. So, in those companies, cheap and fast are the right objectives, and everything else is a luxury.

Comment: @bubba thank you for your answer. I do think that something has happened to the world, I mean, maths exist by itself, people created a language so that one can exchange with each other, and we discover things that exist independently of human beings. I think God has created the Universe and its mathematical description. We are just playing with it, but we haven't done anything. Though finance and data science don't come from God but from human misperception of Universe, imo.

Comment: @bubba you are totally right, I do see maths like a branch of art. I know that almost nobody cares of it, so in this world based on money that's problematic. I would rather have dreamed of a world without the concept of money where we all take part in our everyday needs, e.g. raising vegetables and animals, then make cheese from them, and knitting clothes, and building our own houses. All this based from the help of one another :) Therefore one would have some spare time to do one's hobby like maths or whatever you love even if it is not useful... :)

Comment: @bubba indeed i hope that anyway i will have some time to continue my research whatever will be my path. But still i find it sad and depressing not appreciating one's job, it takes a lot of time in life, 8 hours a day 5 days a week! for 30 years until retirement, i find it terribly long if i don't like what i do. In fact i have worked a year for hospital doing programming between my PhD and first postdoc, and i didn't like it at all, so it is hard to go into this for the rest of my career :/

Comment: @TimothyChow i never said i was not contradictory. I understand your point of view, but it is how i lived until last month - doing not useful maths and still being paid. The only useful part that we do is to teach, but this represents only 20% of our work (in Switzerland).
Please see my reply to bubba just above regarding my problems with the concept of money and society

Comment: Well, you can go somewhere and live as a self-sufficient farmer, if that’s how you want to provide yourself with food, clothing, and shelter. But that’s a taxing full-time job, and you might not have enough time/energy left over to do mathematics. At the other end of the spectrum, you might be able to make enough money to live by working 20 hours/week as a contract programmer.

Comment: @bubba no i didn't mean that i wanted to become a farmer.. :) here it is difficult to find a job at 20h/week, in general it is 40h/week.

Answer (score 17):

I sympathize with you, because I have been in a similar situation. I was in mathematics because it fascinated me, although sometimes more than others. The reason I left mathematics research was not so much that I got tired from all the moving around, but that I wanted to do something "in the real world." I felt that my kind of research was hard to justify to anyone but a specialist, and that mattered to me.

But when I started to make an inventory of options that were available to me on the regular job market, I found out, exactly like you, that the vast majority of jobs for which a mathematics degree is a requirement (or even a plus) struck me as particularly "soulless." I know that might strike some as harsh, but I don't mean to be, that's simply how it felt at the time. I was in mathematics for the joy of it, and it is hard to square this with the purely utilitarian approach to math you find in finance or data science.

In the end I got a job in software development, which at first seemed just as soulless or maybe even more. However I never regretted my decision to leave mathematics. The joy that mathematics had to offer that I just mentioned was of a very elusive kind: sometimes it was there in abundance, but I could never hold on to it. It wasn't a constant stream of inspiration, and what's worse I rarely experienced it during my own "research" (if I could call it that), but almost always by reading about the exciting work done by others. And it didn't have to be cutting edge either.

So yes, quitting the academic career path was a major adjustment, and a period where I experienced loss. I was no longer allowed to devote my life to the pursuit of knowledge and understanding. Worse, I started to question whether I hadn't in fact thrown away fifteen years of my life. But there is light on the other end of the tunnel. These are after all not math problems, but life problems. If you make a decision that you *know* is right, then, with God's grace, it will prove to be so in the end.

Comment: Within the big area of SW-development I'd point out that for people strong in mathematics implementing/developing cryptographic algorithms (likely protected against side-channel attacks) is a fun topic where learning to program the right programming language(s) and the necessary cryptographic background shouldn't be hard for a math PhD.

Comment: It's also a really really hard problem. Computers have side-channels that the manufacturers insist don't exist. Worthwhile, too, if you think cryptography's better to have than not.

Comment: +1 software developer (I left academia after my algebra PhD). I recommend getting into functional programming if you can - I'm a Scala dev now - since this uses category theory and is generally more abstract and mathematical in a way that works well for someone with a maths background. But programming in general scratches the same problem-solving-using-logical-deduction itch that I loved about doing maths. It's just that the problems are much smaller and more tractable, which on the one hand means the highs don't compare but on the other means you don't get stuck nearly as long (IME).

Comment: Also, on the soulless front - you *can* find jobs where you're doing meaningful work in tech, it just takes some effort, may mean you need to make sacrifices in other areas (chosen programming language, amount of tech debt, location, salary, etc.), and it's possible you can only be that selective once you have experience under your belt. But among others I've worked on software for healthcare and public transport and very much felt we were creating something meaningful that would help people.

Comment: @RP_ many thanks for sharing your story. What kind of software do you develop? Are you happy in your job? Did you have programming skills before or you learnt on the spot?

Comment: @coco I could probably more accurately describe myself as a web developer. I develop .NET web applications for a decent-sized company, think online shopping, B2B apps, and the CRM app for internal use. It has absolutely zero to do with mathematics. But there is a lot of creative problem solving involved, and the more experience you have, the more you get to see that.

Comment: @coco As for your other questions, I can't say that I'm happy with my job. I guess I am still figuring things out. The question you raise (and some of the answers you got) have really made me think, and I just wanted to share my own story. Particularly the point made by Kapil about our demand for a job that is commensurate with our qualifications (and frankly, isn't this part of the reason we embarked on higher education in the first place?). I wonder how liberating it would be to let go of that demand. But honestly I wouldn't know what I'd do even if I let go of it.

Comment: As for programming skills, I would say I had quite a bit of programming *experience*, but not so much programming *skills*. Programming is harder than you might think. In mathematics, one way we learn is by not shying away from the very basic questions, e.g. "What is a real number?" and then ending up with Cauchy sequences or Dedekind cuts. Likewise, in programming one should force oneself to attend to the details. If you made a mistake, go back and analyze it, what was the real moment when the mistake was made? I do not always do this, by any means, but when I do it pays off.

Comment: I would describe this as taking a professional attitude to your work (I am basing this on what I've learnt from Robert C. Martin, whom I admire a great deal). I don't always do this, but I aspire to it. And I think this is where you can actually get the same kind of enjoyment that you get from doing mathematics on a high level.

Answer (score 16):

There are two types of career paths for a pure mathematics PhD holder who wants to continue to pursue pure mathematics:

1. Mathematics-related jobs, typically in academia: Most people only look at university jobs which involve teaching and research in roughly balanced proportions. However, one should not ignore school and college teaching positions. These *can* be extremely rewarding *and* can lead to interesting research questions *in* pure mathematics.
2. Jobs entirely unrelated to mathematics: Here the opportunities are limited only by the current job market in your location. Note that a PhD is a higher qualification than what most people in the job market have. (In some places this could unfortunately be a dis-qualification.) It would then be incumbent on you to pursue mathematics on your own; which may be possible provided your job does not suck up your time and mind-space.

Unfortunately, many people are caught in the trap of looking for a job that "is commensurate with their qualifications" where the measurement is based external factors like remuneration and respect from society at large. Such jobs may require you to give up pure mathematics. The alternative is to look for a job which is *sufficient* to support the goal of pursuing one's primary interests.

Here is a tale that may be inspirational. The person who taught me music was a skilled worker in a workshop (factory-type). Even though it did not pay very well, it provided adequate support as far as he was concerned. This allowed him to develop and enjoy his music over a 30-40 year period. He never became famous, but he enjoyed *and* developed his music, and spread this joy to everyone he taught or otherwise came in contact with.

Comment: +1 teaching math at a 4-year or 2-year college.  (Many of these even require Ph.D.) Look into this if non-academic positions seem pointless to you.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar the problem with teaching in high school is that one needs to deal with discipline problems rather than teaching maths.. also one needs to study another 2 years to have the right to teach.

Comment: @kapil thanks for the story of the musician :)

Answer (score 8):

I got a PhD in math and was on this path myself, so I understand. The number one thing you have to realize is that math for the sake of its beauty is hard to pursue even in research academia sometimes. Therefore, keep that part separated in your mind.

The next thing you should do is re-evaluate exactly what you want to do in life, regardless of whether it involved math or not. In other words, keep a blank slate. You basically have to do this because as I said, outside of academia you will never find something that will suit your ideals and in fact it's often hard inside academia. (For example, I love the beauty of math but find the mainstream of endless specialization in huge overarching fields not my thing.)

Once you decide what will really make you happy, just go for it even if it's not math-related. Why? Because you will be much happier doing math on the side than you EVER will be doing a math-related job that doesn't appeal to your ideals. Personally, it only took me a couple years of doing math that didn't appeal to me to make me lose a lot of my passion for it.

My only other advice is get a high-paying job like software development or something applied for 4-5 years. Be frugal and save up a ton of money and then just use it to pursue your passions. Make a plan to exit the traditional system and just do it and don't look back. Math does not define you as a person and I am sure that once you find your center, you will understand what you need to do.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! Indeed that's my problem, i do not know what i want to do in life. I know that life in academia is also not paradise, but at least there is a part of it that we like. Though it is true that i don't like pressure and i like to have enough time to think about something, which in general is until i find the solution. But that solution can come in a too big amount of time, and one needs to publish regularly enough, so one should work on a project that will work for sure.

Comment: So you are right that doing math as a hobby also has an advantage if we have time to. I have seen your photos, they are absolutely gorgeous!! :)

Comment: @coco - Thank you :) I agree, a job in academia is relatively good and should allow you to explore your interests part of the time. I hope you find your path. It's not always easy to do so.

Answer (score 6):

Some of the recently emerged fields in machine learning have a bit of overlap with mathematics (not sure how pure they are). I'm going to name a few that comes to mind:

- **Graph theory**: a recently introduced network architecture known as [graph neural network](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.08434) can be considered a generalization of belief propagation networks on structured graph. This may in addition have some overlap with statistical physics.
- **Algebra/geometry**: [equivariant neural networks](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-022-29939-5) require some sort of explicit/implicit symmetry built into each layer, and very recently people have studied this type of network with symmetry related to certain Lie algebras
- **Topology/measure theory**: to give a marginally related example, [normalization flows](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.09257) are neural networks that attempts to "continuously" deform a Gaussian measure to some other non-trivial (usually multi-modal) measures. For instance, people have used the Banach fixed point theorem to show such networks are actually "trainable".
- **Complexity theory**: [transformers](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.06732) are a type of network that requires quadratic memory and compute to perform inference. Recently, people have investigated ways to reduce its complexity theory methods such as [hashing](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.04451) and [kernel methods](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.14794).
- **Optimization theory**: currently the way neural networks are trained are somewhat ad hoc, and people just use whatever optimizers (e.g. Adam, SAM) that gives the best empirical results. Recently, people have started looking into this more seriously, and [neural ODE](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.07366) is a type of network that can be trained via the [Pontryagin method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_state_method).
- **Random matrix theory**: [the neural network layer weights can be considered as a random matrix](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.08276), and the heavy-tailness of such matrices have recently be studied as indicators for the "complexity" of the network (and whether it is prone to overfitting).
- **Dynamical systems**: [a group in UWashington](https://www.me.washington.edu/facultyfinder/steve-brunton) are looking at ways to interface machine learning with dynamical systems. For instance, one direction is to use neural networks to discover implicit low-rank structures of nonlinear dynamical systems, such as [SINDY](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.1517384113) for the Navier Stokes.
- **Fourier analysis**: there is a line of research that tries to convert convolution networks [into recurrent networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.00396), by apply Fourier transforms (or polynomial decomposition) to the network inputs and kernels. Many theoretical problems are still open, such as the stability and convergence of such conversion.

However, similar to the case of physics lagging behind mathematics for 50 years or so, most ML fields further lags behind physics 20-30 years. So I wouldn't count on using a ML-related job (research or industry focused) as a medium to gain immediate access to novel mathematical research. Rather, I'd view it as an opportunity to apply your own mathematical knowledge (instead of advancing it).

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer and for providing interesting links! I just wonder how to find such a job, i have never seen job advertisements in these fields.

Comment: @coco I can only speak from my limited experience unfortunately. I initially just went on linkedin and mass applied for a bunch of ML-related jobs (not limited to research), and I just happened land a research-role at a startup that was a good fit. I'd imagine the process to be different for bigger companies, e.g. Google Brain, FAIR, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Writing a good mathematical proof is similar to writing good code. Pure math has much more in common with software engineering than data science.

Comment: The problem is that *coming up with* a mathematical proof is not at all like software engineering, and *writing* the proof is not nearly so enjoyable for a lot of people. It's kind of like suggesting that an aspiring poet become a copyeditor instead.

Answer (score -9):

I have read your question and I am somewhat alarmed and saddened by your current state of being. I feel you need to take a broader perspective in this stage of life, zoom out; Do you really mean your only interest is in math? You also studied physics. You say "I don't have any interest in anything from the society"; are you sure?? You could contribute to medicine; how the brain might work. I'm not going to sum things up what you might do, but it vastly more than just finance or data-science. It is your quest now what else apart from pure math, you find interesting and go from there..

Comment: Not to sound too grumpy, but are you seriously telling someone who's got a PhD in pure maths and has done two postdocs to retool to contribute to medicine after they've said that line of work doesn't interest them? Your answer is not all that helpful, if it is putting the onus back on the OP ("it is your quest") and explicitly avoiding answering the question ("I'm not going to sum up...").

Comment: when i say i don't have interest in the society i mean i don't have a deep enough interest to devote myself to it full time. In fact between my PhD and 1st postdoc i have worked for hospital and learnt a bit of bioinformatics. I didn't like it at all and was very depressed to spend all my working time doing something i don't like. So i would like to find a happier option.